# Woocommerce Subscriptions Signup Fee as Installments

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, subscription

I need to implement Installment option for the Signup fee for Subscription products in my woo-commerce store.

I am using "Woocommerce", "Woocommerce Subscriptions", "Woocmmerce Stripe Gateway" plugins.

I have tried [Woocommerce Installments plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-installments/). But it just splits the Monthly subscription fee in to installments instead of Signup Fee.

I have even tried setting the signup fee of the item as 0 and sending invoice for installments using [WP-Invoice - Web Invoice and Billing](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-invoice/) plugin. But the issues are there is no option for synchronized payment and setting duration.

I have even tried editing the plugin, but it ended up in a mess.

How can I implement this feature and achieve my goal?

Comment: I'm looking for the same result. Did you manage to achieve it?

Comment: Yes. I did it in an alternate way since there was no other option. I created the sign up fees for each subscription types as another separate instalment item(subscription item) with name as signup fee for "that" item. And added coding to make this item (signup instalment) too to be added to the cart once the corresponding subscription item is added. I will send you the detailed code and other info on Monday, since all the codes are in my office PC and there is no office on the weekends.